# history.pushState() change query values

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate

If I have a link that is being changed with the function `history.pushState({}, "", link);` where my `link` is for example `page.php?value=1&value2=2` Is there a way to just change the `value2` with `pushState()` function instead of changing the whole link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is change the URL without adding an additional entry to the history object, you might try `replaceState`.

```
history.replaceState({value: 1, value2: X}, "title", "page.php");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer. Passing an object as the first argument to `replaceState` will not affect the query values in the URL. Only the last argument will: In this example, it will remove the query entirely.

Comment: The OP wanted to update (rather than create a new) a value in the current history state.  While you cannot use pushState to modify a state object, that's the purpose of replaceState.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the query string is part of the URL. If you don't truly need to pass those values for the purposes of the server, you can include them in the history's state object itself, and then you can change just the state object with `pushState()`. For example:

```
history.pushState({value: 1, value2: 2}, "Title", 'page.php');
history.pushState({value: 1, value2: 'new value'}, "Title");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this useful function to change a query string parameter value:

```
function updateParam(url, param, value)
{  
    var re = new RegExp(param+"(.+?)(&|$)","g");

    return url.replace(re, param+'='+value)  
}
```

Comment: That last line should be `url.replace(re, param+'='+value+'$2')`, right? Otherwise you lose the ampersand delimiter.