# Ionic 3: Set URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, ionic3, url-parameters

I am building a PWA in Ionic 3 with Deeplinking. My URL is like this:
http://example.com/#/va/event/e-list

Now I want to add and update URL Params like

- http://example.com/#/va/event/e-list?state=signup-shown
- http://example.com/#/va/event/e-list?state=signedin
- http://example.com/#/va/event/e-list?state=mobile-given
- http://example.com/#/va/event/e-list?state=otp-entered

I need exactly this solution to work with Ionic:
[Set URL parameters without causing page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258793/set-url-parameters-without-causing-page-refresh)

Right now, when I add a url Param manually in browser, Ionic is removing it. Couldn't find any hint in Ionic documentation.

Comment: Did you try [Ionic Page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)

Comment: @Duannx `IonicPage` is what we use to get Deeplinking and I am using that already. But it doesnt seem to support. setting custom URL parameters.

Comment: `IonicPage` has a propertive is [segment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/#dynamic-links). Isn't it what you are finding?

Comment: I tried configuring my `@IonicPage` segment as `segment: nested-tab/?foo=?` But it's not working. When I try to give the URL as nested-tab/?foo-123, Ionic is throwing error `Invalid views to insert` Not sure how to use wildcards characters. Documentation didn't help.

Comment: You should config like that: `nested-tab/:foo`. So when your url is `nested-tab/:3` you will get a `navParams` with `foo=3`

Comment: I get that. But I need to have URL parameters with ?key=value, rather than baseUrl/:value, for 2 reasons. Reason 1: In Google Analytics, `e-list/signup-shown`, `e-list/signedin`, will be taken as separate Pageviews, while they are actually custom evnets and not actual Page views. So defining the URLs as defined in my Question will resolve that issue. Reason 2: In mid of my app, I am redirecting the User to a Payment gateway. When the Payment process is over the payment gateway redirects to my app, passing some Payment Info as GET Params in URL. I need to be able to get those Params & parse it.

Comment: Ya. I got what you mean. I can't help any more in that situation. Hope you can find out the solution

Comment: @saiy2k Did you find a solution for that?