# update parameters in URL with history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I am using `history.pushState` to append few params to current page URL after making an AJAX call on my page. Now on same page based on user action, I want to update the page URL again with same or additional set of params. So my code looks like this:

```
var pageUrl = window.location.href + "?" + queryString;
window.history.pushState('','',pageUrl);
```

queryString is my list of query params.

- For example, My Default page URL: http://sample.com/
- After First AJAX call on same page URL should be: http://sample.com?param1=foo&param2=bar
- After Second AJAX call on same page URL can be:
  http://sample.com/?param1=foo,foo1&param2=bar&param3=another_foo

But with the above code my params are getting appended to URL with the params and they look like below after second AJAX call:

http://sample.com?param1=foo&param2=bar&param1=foo,foo1&param2=bar&param3=another_foo

So the params appear twice in the URL, is there any way of replacing the params in URL before pushing to History or any other better way to achieve this in javascript(jquery) ?

Comment: one way i think of before every update to history I remove all existing query params from URL and add the new query params to URL again and call pushState with new URL. Not sure if this is appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [history.pushState() change query values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420955/history-pushstate-change-query-values)

Comment: Did you every figure this out?

Answer (score 31):

I think what you need is remove `window.location.href` and leave `'?' +`.

```
var pageUrl = '?' + queryString;
window.history.pushState('', '', pageUrl);
```

Comment: That partially solved my issue, your suggestion actually updated the params in the URL but it also replaced my url's last part and removed the query separator "?" from URL ...So if my url was:  http://sample.com/testpage/test?param1=foo&param2=bar, after your suggestion it becomes: http://sample.com/testpage/param1=foo&param2=bar

Comment: queryString parameter is always single string with all params. No duplicates there.

Comment: all right, I see. actually, why it was making your string long is because window.location.href is empty first time and contain ?param1=foo&param2=bar second time. and you're concatenating this href. so updating code to this var pageUrl = "?" + queryString; should solve the issue.

Comment: You might want to add the '=' sign to the ? in pageUrl. Therefore it would become: pageUrl = '?=' + queryString. The url will be https://{domain}?={queryString}

Answer (score 25):

This function might be helpful

```
function updateUrlParameter(param, value) {
    const regExp = new RegExp(param + "(.+?)(&|$)", "g");
    const newUrl = window.location.href.replace(regExp, param + "=" + value + "$2");
    window.history.pushState("", "", newUrl);
}
```

**Edit**: The following solution is simpler, and it also works if the parameter is not yet part of the URL. However, it's not supported by Internet Explorer (you don't say?).

```
function setQueryStringParameter(name, value) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    params.set(name, value);
    window.history.replaceState({}, "", decodeURIComponent(`${window.location.pathname}?${params}`));
}
```

Comment: How would I expand this to add the param if it currently not in the URL?

Comment: Should we be passing `encodeURIComponent()` with the value? e.g. `setQueryStringParameter('name', encodeURIComponent('John Doe'));`

Comment: Your regex would clobber other similar params e.g. if you had `myParam1` and `myParam100`, sending `{ myParam1: "x"}` could potentially affect the `myParam100` parameter which is not what you'd want. So your regex should by updated to something like `new RegExp(param + "(=.*?)?(&|$)", "g")` which allows for parameters with/without an = and/or value.

Answer (score 13):

In order to keep the last part of the url and just play with parameters, you can create a new URL object like so:

```
// e.g url: sample.com/testpage/test

var url = new URL(window.location);
url.searchParams.set('foo', 'bar');
window.history.pushState({}, '', url);

// outcome: sample.com/testpage/test?foo=bar

// you can remove, just the param part, like so:
url.searchParams.delete('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Manage query parameters in the current URL

This function is similar to the other answers, but without using RegExp and string concatenations.

Args:

- name - string name of the query parameter.
- value - string value of the parameter.
- append - if true: this function always adds a new parameter. This is very useful when you need to add two parameters with the same name, e.g.: `localhost:8080/some_page?foo=100500&foo=ABC`. Otherwise, the parameter will be changed (or added if absent).

```js
function setQueryStringParameter(name, value, append=false) {
    const url = new URL(window.document.URL);
    if (append) url.searchParams.append(name, value);
    else url.searchParams.set(name, value);
    window.history.replaceState(null, "", url.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let baseurl =
      window.location.protocol +
      "//" +
      window.location.host +
      window.location.pathname;
    console.log("baseurl : " + baseurl);
    window.history.pushState(undefined, undefined, baseurl + "?" + params);
```

Comment: If you want to replace the entire parameters string then above code can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Simply appending `window.location.search` to the end of my route does the trick for me:

Assuming that `user.id` and `post.id` are well defined string:

```js
window.history.replaceState(
  null,
  "",
  `/users/${user.id}/${post.id}${window.location.search}`,
);
```

Quoting the type definition of `window.location.search`

> Returns the Location object's URL's query (includes leading "?" if non-empty).
> Can be set, to navigate to the same URL with a changed query (ignores leading "?").