# Setting or Appending Multiple Options in URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im attempting to filter results via the URL in jQuery. Currently I can get and `decodeURL` to get my results to update correctly.

My issue is maintaining the URL in this logical format. e.g.

`https://example.com/members?buys=Cheese,Ham&sells=Dog%20Food`

I cant for the life of me get this working. I've listed out the functions I found from around the internet and modified to get progress on this.

This function replaces the current param so cant set multiple select options.

```
function setQueryStringParameter(name, value) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    params.set(name, value);
    window.history.replaceState({}, "", `${location.pathname}?${params}`);
}
```

The `params.set` can be replaced with `params.append` but this makes the url `buys=Cheese&buys=Ham&sells=Dog%2520Food`. I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41505583/878344) and changed it to match my getParamFunction (it runs `decodeURL`). Notice the incorrect or double encoding on the `sells=Dog%2520Food` that happens.

No matter what I search I cant find any information that covers maintaining multiple options inside a URL correctly encoded.

Comment: How about joining all filters with `,` as the separator into a string and on decoding splitting them using the same separator?

Comment: Im currently decoding that way, the issue is getting them to arrange by `,` separator Im not sure what Im doing incorrectly. Im hoping someone has done this before and can provide a easy function I can drop in and learn from.

Comment: The behaviour you are seeing is how the URLSearchParams work. Check the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams To prevent that you could always concatenate the values before setting the parameter value.