# Update query string in url

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update the url query string by clicking on checkbox. Here's the code, it doesn't work correctly

```
param1=param1=true
param1=param1=param1=false
param1=param1=param1=param1=true
```

instead of:

```
param1=false
param1=true
```

Here's an unrefactored code:

```
if (this.checked) {
      if (window.location.href.search('[?&]') === -1) {
        window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', window.location.href + '?param1=true');  
      } else {
        window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', window.location.href.replace(/param1=false|true/i, 'param1=true'));   
      }

    } else {
      if (window.location.href.search('[?&]') === -1) {
        window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', window.location.href + '?param1=false');  
      } else {
        window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', window.location.href.replace(/param1=false|true/i, 'param1=false'));   
      }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)

Comment: @Bhullnatik, you better reread my question.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420955/history-pushstate-change-query-values, though that question doesn't yet seem to have a terribly satisfactory answer. (You could of course try adding a bounty.)

Comment: @JoLiss, reread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
> 'param1=false'.replace(/param1=false|true/i, 'param1=true')
"param1=true"
> 'param1=true'.replace(/param1=false|true/i, 'param1=true')
"param1=param1=true"
> 'true'.replace(/param1=false|true/i, 'param1=true')
"param1=true"
```

The thing is that your regular expression is accepting either `param1=false` or just `true`. You need to put the `false|true` part in a group (in parentheses) to make the `|` not apply to the `param1=` part too. So your regular expression should be `/param1=(false|true)/i`:

```
> 'param1=true'.replace(/param1=(false|true)/i, 'param1=true')
'param1=true'
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other parameters in your query string, you could reconstruct your url like this:

```
var href = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
if (this.checked) {
    window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', href + '?param1=true');  
} else {
    window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', href + '?param1=false');   
}
```