# Update query string (no redirect) without HTML 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Can I update a query string parameter without reload the page? I know that, there are some HTML5 features (history.pushState, etc.) but it doesn't work on many browsers (or browser versions)...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually browser support is [quite good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) nowadays, IE10+ and all other major browser support *session history management*. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10421866/1456376) how to modify the current parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without history.pushState.

There's a polyfill using the hash (#) portion of the URL as it can be changed without reloading even on old browsers, but it doesn't cover all use cases (bookmarking and sharing for instance).

You might want to look into history.js for graceful degradation and simplicity of use.